# what is correct usecase of push() and callback() methods of ExitStack?

Tags: python-3.x

I have read Python documentation about ExitStack but I am not able to understand how to apply or use `push()` and `callback()` to practical example.

I have tried basic example of Exitstack to open multiple context manager and understood the practical working of `enter_context()`, `pop_all()` and `close()` method.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
path = './folder/'
fileList = ['File1', 'File2', 'File3']

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(path+file)) for file in fileList]

    close_files = stack.pop_all().close

    for f in files:
        print(f.read())

    close_files()



path = './folder/'
fileList = ['File1', 'File2', 'File3']

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(path+file)) for file in fileList]

    close_files = stack.pop_all().close

    mergedFile = open(path+'mergedFile', 'w+')
    stack.callback(mergedFile.close)

    for f in files:
        print(mergedFile.writelines(f.readlines()))

    close_files()
```

Comment: `stack.callback(mergedFile.close)`? `callback` requires a... callback (a function); `mergedFile.close` is a function, `mergedFile.close()` is nothing (like most side-effectful functions in Python), and you've closed a file prematurely. I don't see any `push` in your code though, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: close() method registers the callback not closes the file . File will be close when exiting the with statement. An you are correct about using close instead of close(). It works fine.

Comment: Can you show an any example to demonsrate the correct use of push() method?